# Elements loading separately jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Im trying to convert this function into one that will take into account each string change to image, right now this only updates only one image per table row.

```js
$('*')
  .filter(function () {
    return !$(this).children().length;
  })
  .html(function (index, old) {
    return old.replace(
      'Englisch',
      '<img class="bydcode-language-flag" src="wp-content/themes/boss-child/bydcode/flags/united-kingdom-flag-medium.png" alt="Englisch">'
    );
  });

$('*')
  .filter(function () {
    return !$(this).children().length;
  })
  .html(function (index, old) {
    return old.replace(
      'Spanisch',
      '<img class="bydcode-language-flag" src="wp-content/themes/boss-child/bydcode/flags/spain-flag-medium.png" alt="Spanisch">'
    );
  });

$('*')
  .filter(function () {
    return !$(this).children().length;
  })
  .html(function (index, old) {
    return old.replace(
      'Deutsche',
      '<img class="bydcode-language-flag" src="wp-content/themes/boss-child/bydcode/flags/germany-flag-medium.png" alt="Deutsche">'
    );
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('*')
  .filter(function () {
    return !$(this).children().length;
  })
  .html(function (index, old) {
    return old.replace(
      lang
      '<img class="bydcode-language-flag" src=`${getFlag(lang)}` alt=`${lang}`  />'
    );
  });
```

and add a utility method that resolves flags

```js
function getFlag(lang) {
  switch(flag) {
     case "Spanisch":
        return "wp-content/themes/boss-child/bydcode/flags/spain-flag-medium.png";
    case "another-lang":
       return "wp-content/themes/boss-child/bydcode/flags/another-flag-medium.png";
   }
}
```